# Storage and scalability benefits in HDFS

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, storage, scalability, hdfs

I have certain doubts on storage and scalability of HDFS----

Firstly
ie 1 TB on a normal SQL Server data file will also be approx. equal to 1 TB on HDFS.
 So is there any benefits of using HDFS.

Please clarrify the doubt(I don't know whether it is correct or incorrect)

Secondly

Huge performance gain ie in reading and writing comes from parallelism due to the multiple nodes handling each read/write operation.

Is this hypothesis correct

Please clarify the doubts

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The question is phrased rather wide but I'd think the best resource that addresses it is Konstantin Shvachko's paper on [HDFS scalability: the limits to growth](http://static.usenix.org/publications/login/2010-04/openpdfs/shvachko.pdf).